# Is there a Swan-style description of topological K-homology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

A celebrated result of Swan [1] states that, on a compact Hausdorff space $X$, the category of finite rank complex vector bundles is equivalent to the category of finitely generated projective $\mathcal{C}(X)$-modules, where $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is the ring of complex-valued continuous functions on $X$ (analogous statements are true over the reals and the quaternions *(loc.cit.)*, but these will not concern us here). One can look upon this in the following ways:

- interesting geometric objects and their morphisms-- *viz.* complex vector bundles of finite rank and vector bundle maps -- have a description by interesting algebraic objects and their morphisms *viz.* finitely generated projective modules and their morphisms;
- just the other way round: interesting algebraic objects and their morphisms have a description by interesting geometric objects and their morphisms;
- as a synthesis of these views one obtains that a topological invariant, the complex $K$-theory $K(X)$ of $X$, has both a geometric description by complex vector bundles and an algebraic description by projective modules.

Pondering a while upon these issues the following questions come to mind:

> - The category of finite rank vector bundles is additive, but not abelian. This may lead one to consider linear fibrations over $X$ which are locally modelled on the kernels or cokernels of vector bundle maps of finite rank vector bundles; these have fibres which are vector spaces of possibly varying finite dimension.
>   To which algebraic objects do these correspond?

> - Are there further algebraic categories of $\mathcal{C}(X)$-modules with an interesting geometric description? In particular, do the finitely generated $\mathcal{C}(X)$-modules have an interesting geometric description?

> - Does the topological $K$-homology $K_*(X)$ of $X$ have interesting geometrical and algebraic descriptions? The $K$-theory of finiteley generated $\mathcal{C}(X)$-modules appears to fail here, since pushing forward does not seem to work.

[1] Swan, R.G. --
Vector bundles and projective modules. *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 105*, (1962), 264–277.

Comment: With regard to your third question, there's is a [“geometric” picture of $K$-homology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Baum-Douglas+geometric+cycle) due to Baum and Douglas. If you don't mind a little analysis, though, the pairing between $K$-homology and $K$-theory can be beautifully understood in terms of the [Atiyah–Singer index theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233144/atiyah-singer-theorem-a-big-picture?rq=1) and its various generalisations in index theory and noncommutative geometry.